# How to load a .db file into MySQL or any other open source DB?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a .db (database file) file and I want to load it into my MySQL database. how can i do this?
If not MySQL then any other open source DB is also fine.

Comment: is it a SQLite database file?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: can you open with a text editor or is it a binary file? if it's binary you can try to open it for example with with http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: I am unable to open it in sqlitebrowser, it says invalid format. Also, if I open it in wordpad, I can read half the text, the other half seems gibberish.

Comment: It has binary data in it...

Comment: it could be anything... do you know where it comes from?